# asp.net mvc fill a dropdownlist according to the item selected in an author

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

i'm a total beginner in asp.net mvc and am trying to change the items in a dropdownlist according to the item selected in an author one (they are filled from a database)

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" })) 
{
  Filiere: <%= Html.DropDownList("filiere", (SelectList)ViewData["filiere"], new { onchange =      "this.form.submit();" })%>

  Module:<%= Html.DropDownList("module",(SelectList)ViewData["module"])
 }
%>

    public ActionResult Index(int? fil)
    {
        var fi = db.filiere.Select(f => new {f.id,f.nom });
        ViewData["filiere"] = new SelectList(fi.AsEnumerable(), "id", "nom");
        List<module> mod;
        if (fil == null)
            mod = db.module.ToList();
        else
        {
            mod = (from module in db.module
                   where module.id_filiere == fil
                   select module).ToList();
        }
        ViewData["module"] = new SelectList(mod.AsEnumerable(),"id","nom");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: the problem is when selecting a item in the first dropdownlist everything goes back to default nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Try to create one more method in controller who accept the author information and return the list which you want to display in drop-down.

then simply put ajax call on author change event call the controller method for data and also pass current author information and on success bind result what you get from controller method to drop-down.

Comment: thank you for answering :) well as i said i'm a beginners in this, if possible could you give me an example ?

Comment: look this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/765519/ASP-NET-MVC-for-Beginners-in-Web-Development) :D and every one beginner in some stages...